# conversion of a varchar datatype to a datetime datatype resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server

The conversion of a varchar datatype to a datetime datatype resulted in an out-of-range value

```
select a.DLNO,
       a.NAME,
       b.TOPSTRING,
       Convert(datetime,a.DOB,103) as DOB, 
       Convert(datetime,a.DOI,103) as DOI,
       Convert(datetime,b.datepushed,103) as datepushed 
from    
       PLInfo_Demo a,DLInfo_Demo b 
where 
       a.dlno=b.DLNO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `103` requires that you have datetimes with the European date/month order: `'dd/mm/yyyy'`

If you store month first, this may result in this error (say for `'01/13/2012'`)

If it's the case, use type `101` (`'mm/dd/yyyy'`)

It's always better to store datetimes as `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_helptext sp_displayClinicRecordsbyclinicid


alter procedure sp_displayClinicRecordsbyclinicid

(

@id bigint,

@category char(1)

)

as


select id,ClinicName,

CONVERT(varchar(10), cast(Visitdate as datetime),101) Visitdate ,

CONVERT(varchar(19), cast(visitTime as datetime) ,101)  visitTime ,

patient_first,patient_last,patient_address,patient_city,patient_state, CONVERT(varchar(10), cast(patient_dob as datetime),101) patient_dob,



precriber,prescriptionnum,CONVERT(varchar(10),cast(pharmacyfilldate as datetime) ,101)  pharmacyfilldate,CONVERT(varchar(10),cast(prescriptionenddate as datetime) ,101) prescriptionenddate,drugname,drugformat,npi,dea,



licence,clinicid,Category,PatientFullname,Prescriber_first,Prescriber_last,Qty,Days



 from tblClinicRecords where clinicid=@id and Category=@category
```